# This may be a newb thing... but, global variables

Tags: python, variables

Ok! Basically, I have a variable being declared in one function, and I would like to use that variable in another function. I do not want to pass parameters, because I feel like there would be a simpler way to do this. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import os
import time
print ("Hello and welcome to Pygame!")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Would you like to load? (\"Y/N\")")

def LON():
    loadOrNew = raw_input()

    if loadOrNew == "N":
        hp = 100
        strhp = str(hp)
        lvl = 1
        strlvl = str(lvl)
        atk = 5
        stratk = str(atk)
        defn = 2
        strdefn = str(defn)
        fout = open("pygame.dat", "w")
        fout.write (strhp) 
        fout.write("\n")
        fout.write(strlvl)
        fout.write("\n")
        fout.write(stratk)
        fout.write("\n")
        fout.write(strdefn)
        fout.close()
        FIRSTPLAY()
        return

    if loadOrNew == "Y":
        fin = open("pygame.dat", "r")
        hpstr = fin.readline()
        lvlstr = fin.readline()
        atkstr = fin.readline()
        defstr = fin.readline()
        hp = int(float(hpstr))
        lvl = int(float(lvlstr))
        atk = int(float(atkstr))
        defn = int(float(defnstr))
        fin.close()
        return

    if loadOrNew != "Y" and loadOrNew != "N":
        print("Im sorry, what?")
        LON()
        return

    return

def SAVE():
    fout = open("pygame.dat", "w")
    fout.write(hp)
    fout.write(lvl)
    fout.write(atk)
    fout.close(defn)
    return


def FIRSTPLAY():
    print("man/woman?")
    gender = raw_input()
    if gender != "man" and gender != "woman":
        print("Not valid gender.")
        FIRSTPLAY()

    print("KING - ")    
    print(" Young " + gender + ", you are herby my knight!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" My daughter, princess PYTHON, has been captured!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" You are to find her, and relieve this world of her captor!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" Some say this evil man's name is GAMEMAKER, but we really don't know.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" What do you think it is?")
    captor = raw_input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" So you think it is " + captor + "?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("     Very well, find " + captor + " ASAP!")
    PLAY()
    return

def PLAY():
    print hp
    print lvl
    print atk
    print defn
    greenSlime(hp, lvl, atk, defn)
    return

def greenSlime(php, plvl, patk, pdefn):
    MHP = 10
    MLVL = 1
    MATK = 2
    MDEF = 2
    print "Green Slime - "
    print " HP: 10"
    print " LVL: 1"
    print " ATK: 2"
    print " DEF: 2"
    print "ATK OR DEF?"

LON()
```

I would like to use hp, lvl, atk, and defn variables that were declared in the LON function, in the PLAY function. I'm sure there is a simpler way then passing parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declaring a variable inside global will not work. The global keyword is to ask the interpreter not to treat something as a local (overriding a global variable with the same name) when assigning a value to it. What you need to do is define the variable at a scope above the functions which are supposed to share it. Note that you don't need to declare a variable global in function for read-only access. When the interpreter does not find the variable in local scope it automatically looks for it at outer scope. But in case of assignment statement, it creates a new local variable.

So what you want to do is :

```
hp = None
lvl = None
atk = None
defn = None

def LON():
    global hp, lvl, atk, defn
    # rest of LON

# rest of the functions
```

But I should warn you that globals are bad programming practice and passing parameters is the right way to do it.

Comment: Actually, in the code above, all there is needed is to keep the data in a dictionary, and pass this single dictionary as a parameter along the functions.

Comment: The thing is, almost ALL the functions are going to need these variables, and it would be a pain to pass ALL these functions. I also need to change the functions in these variables, so its a pain :/

Answer (score 1):

Inside `LON()`, you can use the `global` statement:

```
def LON():
    global hp, lvl, atk, defn
```

Then, assignments to those variables inside `LON()` will create global variables. Once the global variables are created, you can use them elsewhere (without needing a `global` statement). Note that anywhere you want to *assign* a new value to the global variable, you will need a corresponding `global` statement inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to move the functions into a python class. That way all functions inside the class can access the variables, without you needing to make them global.

You'd probably structure the code something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import os
import time
print ("Hello and welcome to Pygame!")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Would you like to load? (\"Y/N\")")

class Game:

  def InitialiseNewPlayer(self):
    self.hp = 100
    self.lvl = 1
    self.atk = 5
    self.defn = 2

  def SavePlayer(self):
    fout = open("pygame.dat", "w")
    fout.write ( str(self.hp) ) 
    fout.write("\n")
    fout.write(str(self.lvl) )
    fout.write("\n")
    fout.write(str(self.atk) )
    fout.write("\n")
    fout.write(str(self.defn) )
    fout.close()

  def LoadPlayer(self):
     fin = open("pygame.dat", "r")
     self.hp = int(float(fin.readline()))
     self.lvl = int(float(fin.readline()))
     self.atk = int(float(fin.readline()))
     self.defn = int(float(fin.readline()))
     fin.close()

  def LON(self):
    while true:
      loadOrNew = raw_input()

      if loadOrNew == "N":
        self.InitialiseNewPlayer()
        self.SavePlayer();
        self.FIRSTPLAY()
        return

      if loadOrNew == "Y":
        self.LoadPlayer()
        return

      print("Im sorry, what?")

  # Watch out as this is using a different format to the SavePlayer above!
  def SAVE(self):
    fout = open("pygame.dat", "w")
    fout.write(self.hp)
    fout.write(self.lvl)
    fout.write(self.atk)
    fout.close(self.defn)


  def FIRSTPLAY(self):
    print("man/woman?")
    gender = raw_input()
    if gender != "man" and gender != "woman":
        print("Not valid gender.")
        FIRSTPLAY()

    print("KING - ")    
    print(" Young " + gender + ", you are herby my knight!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" My daughter, princess PYTHON, has been captured!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" You are to find her, and relieve this world of her captor!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" Some say this evil man's name is GAMEMAKER, but we really don't know.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" What do you think it is?")
    captor = raw_input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" So you think it is " + captor + "?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("     Very well, find " + captor + " ASAP!")
    self.PLAY()
    return

  def PLAY(self):
      print self.hp
      print self.lvl
      print self.atk
      print self.defn
      self.greenSlime()

  def greenSlime(self):
    MHP = 10
    MLVL = 1
    MATK = 2
    MDEF = 2
    print "Green Slime - "
    print " HP: 10"
    print " LVL: 1"
    print " ATK: 2"
    print " DEF: 2"
    print "ATK OR DEF?"

game = Game()
game.LON()
```